# How to get dynamic NSMenu to use Mojave Dark Mode?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenu, macos-darkmode

My OS is set to dark mode, and my whole app renders properly, except for some dynamically created NSMenu instances, which render in the old light style.

How do I get those menus to render using a dark visual style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dark visual style is only applied if you specify the parent view.

If `view` is `nil` here, the old style will be used instead:

```
NSMenu* menu;
NSView* view; // cannot be nil
[menu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:NSMakePoint(0, 0) inView:view];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented `apperance` argument for `popUpMenuPositioningItem`. You have to customize the existing `NSMenu` class to use it:

```
@interface NSMenu ()
- (BOOL)popUpMenuPositioningItem:(nullable NSMenuItem *)item atLocation:(NSPoint)location inView:(nullable NSView *)view appearance:(nullable NSAppearance *)appearance NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_6);
@end
```

If you want to use it in Swift via `popUp` you have to declare it in an "Objective-C Bridging Header" file and add the path to the Xcode project's build settings under "Swift Compiler - General"

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/blob/a3227204e1eaa6c450fd5028dc2519c7d92f432e/extensions/menubar/internal.m) and [here](https://github.com/ian4hu/Clipy/blob/fe0eb480ac4958e266526d6a63dcdcc3b210df6b/Clipy/Sources/Clipy-Bridging-Header.h). Class extension is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1).